# Protected member not accessible in a derived class?

Tags: c#, oop, event-handling, protected, access-modifiers

I have a base class `O`, and two derived classes: `A : O`, and `B : O` like this:

```
public abstract class O
{
    public O(string val)
    {
        this.Value = val;
    }

    private string value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            RaiseValueChanged();
        }
    }

    protected delegate void ValueChangedEventHandler();
    protected event ValueChangedEventHandler ValueChanged;
    protected void RaiseValueChanged()
    { if (ValueChanged != null) ValueChanged(); }
}

public sealed class A : O
{
    public A(string val)
        : base(val) { }
}

public sealed class B : O
{
    public B(string val, A instance)
        : base(val)
    {
        instanceA = instance;
    }

    private A instanceA;
    public A InstanceA
    {
        get { return instanceA; }
        set
        {
            instanceA = value;
        }
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //Some stuff..
    }
}
```

I want to call `B.MyMethod();` when `B.instanceA.ValueChanged` is raised, but I was surprised when I found out that I can't just do it like this:

```
public sealed class B : O
{
    public B(string val, A instance)
        : base(val)
    {
        instanceA = instance;
        //instanceA.ValueChanged += MyMethod;
    }

    private A instanceA;
    public A InstanceA
    {
        get { return instanceA; }
        set
        {
            //instanceA.ValueChanged -= MyMethod;
            instanceA = value;
            //instanceA.ValueChanged += MyMethod;
        }
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //Some stuff..
    }
}
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx):

> The protected keyword is a member access modifier. A protected member
>   is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.

But although both `A`, and `B` were derived classes from `O`, they couldn't use each other's base protected members.

Any suggestions to get around this in my case? (instead of making the event `public`)

Comment: Why don't you want to make this event public? Do you want only specific types to be able to register?

Comment: `B` does not inherit from `A` that's why you can't access this event. They share the same base but do not inherit.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, I want only the `O` derived classes to register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `O`, `A` and `B` are all in the same assembly, you could use `internal` if you don't want it to be public. Otherwise you are limited to `public` access in this case.

When you try to access a base class member in this way, you are accessing it via the `public` API only, not via `protected`. You can see this for yourself by trying the following:

```
public sealed class B : O
{
    public B(string val, O instance)
        : base(val)
    {
        instanceO = instance;
        instanceO.ValueChanged += MyMethod;
    }

    private O instanceO;
}
```

This still gives a compilation error. You can access `ValueChanged` in `B`, but only via an instance of `B`, as it says in the quote:

> The protected keyword is a member access modifier. A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class *instances*

(emphasis mine).

Answer (score 1):

> But although both `A`, and `B` were derived classes from `O`, they couldn't use each other's base protected members.

This is to be expected.

> A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.

`A` is derived from `O`, not `B` so there's no way that it can see the protected members of `B` (and vice versa).

If you want to these classes to be able to see each other's members/events/etc, then you'll need to make them public.

Answer (score 0):

You have instanceA as a field of class B. Protected is used to be accessed inside derived class, but not outside. So there is only one solution - to use public.

Comment: There is another solution: `internal`.

Comment: But it also will make this event visible to another classes in assembly

Comment: Yes, but as I see Aly wants to hide event at all, so public or internal - it is not significant

Answer (score 0):

Make it public and try this.

This will guarantee two things.

First, the caller off the event handler attach operation is a member (or static) method of a class derived from O,

Second, the delegate passed as the event handler is a member (or static) method of a class derived from O.

```
public delegate void ValueChangedEventHandler();

private event ValueChangedEventHandler valueChanged;
public event ValueChangedEventHandler ValueChanged
{
    add
    {
        if (!typeof(O).IsAssignableFrom(value.Method.DeclaringType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        if (!typeof(O).IsAssignableFrom(new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        valueChanged += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        valueChanged -= value;
    }
}
```